# Python get file from Clipboard with winapi through DragQueryFile returns nothing

Tags: python, winapi, clipboard

I am trying to make a simple Python program, which gets the currently copied file from the Clipboard. I am using the windll to achieve this. I used some code from the already existing pyperclip tool(can only get text not files) and I tried to adapt it to get the currently copied files.

Here is the Documentation for the function I am calling : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776408(v=vs.85).aspx

Reference for Clipboard Functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468802(v=vs.85).aspx

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from ctypes import c_size_t, sizeof, c_wchar_p, get_errno, c_wchar, c_ulong, c_uint32

class CheckedCall(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        super(CheckedCall, self).__setattr__("f", f)

    def __call__(self, *args):
        ret = self.f(*args)
        if not ret and get_errno():
            raise PyperclipWindowsException("Error calling " + self.f.__name__)
        return ret

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        setattr(self.f, key, value)

windll = ctypes.windll

safeCreateWindowExA = CheckedCall(windll.user32.CreateWindowExA)
safeCreateWindowExA.argtypes = [DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, INT, INT,
                                    INT, INT, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID]
safeCreateWindowExA.restype = HWND

safeDestroyWindow = CheckedCall(windll.user32.DestroyWindow)
safeDestroyWindow.argtypes = [HWND]
safeDestroyWindow.restype = BOOL

OpenClipboard = windll.user32.OpenClipboard
OpenClipboard.argtypes = [HWND]
OpenClipboard.restype = BOOL

clipboarddata=CheckedCall(windll.user32.GetClipboardData)
clipboarddata.argtypes = [UINT]
clipboarddata.restype = HANDLE

safeCloseClipboard = CheckedCall(windll.user32.CloseClipboard)
safeCloseClipboard.argtypes = []
safeCloseClipboard.restype = BOOL

hwnd = safeCreateWindowExA(0, b"STATIC", None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,None, None, None, None)
print(hwnd)
print(OpenClipboard(hwnd))

hendl=clipboarddata(15)
print(hendl)


text = ctypes.create_string_buffer(255)

UINTval=windll.shell32.DragQueryFile(c_uint32(hendl),c_uint32(0),text,c_uint32(255))
print(repr(text.raw))
print(UINTval)


safeCloseClipboard()
```

With a few adjustments this code works perfectly text from the Clipboard, but it just wont work with files. Maybe I am missing something obvious or just misunderstood the specification.

System: Python3.5.2, Windows 8.1

Comment: Why do you assume, that the clipboard were involved in drag and drop?

Comment: I saw it beeing used this way, and i didn´t see anything similar for my cause

Comment: Drag and drop and the clipboard are distinct system services. There is no relation between them other than the fact, that crappy tools use copy-paste as a user-hostile excuse for an implementation of drag and drop.

Comment: So what should I use?

Comment: If a file is copied by means of drag and drop, there's nothing you can do. That's a protocol established between a source and a drop target alone. Unless drag and drop offers interception points to install hooks (which I am unaware of), there's no way to retrieve the information you are after.